# Disable Hyperlink under contidion in aspx page

Tags: asp.net, hyperlink

I need disable this Hyperlink in my aspx page when the value of field `file` on a database is null or empty and I have tried:

```
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Reset">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <center>
                            <asp:HyperLink ID="Reset" runat="server" NavigateUrl=""
                                ImageUrl=""
                                Enabled='<%# !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("file").ToString()) %>' 
                                ToolTip=""
                                BorderStyle="None" ForeColor="Transparent"
                            </asp:HyperLink>
                        </center>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
```

The above solution worked but now need disable this Hyperlink in my aspx page also when the value of field `thedate` is greater of current date.

Can you help me?

Thanks.

Comment: If you want to perform complex business logic, you want to use **DataBound** event. Which **Data** control are you using?

Comment: But I need compare the date of database with current date.

Comment: If it is simple comparison, you can use `DateTime.Parse(Eval("thedate").ToString()) > DateTime.Now`

Comment: Okay but this comparison is added in code behind or in aspx page? I need two conditions for disable the hyperlinh. thank you.

Comment: As I said in 1st comment, you should be performing complex logic in ***DataBound*** event. Since you did not say what ***Data control*** and ***DataSource***, I could not suggest what DataBound event.